# SQL Server Administrative Templates

Tags: sql-server, templates, gpo, administrative

I am trying to setup group policy to exclude SQL Server updates from being installed automatically.  I found information pointing to a SQL Server administrative template that would be useful in this instance.  I tried the below URL that I was able to find but was hit with a 404 File not found error.

> download.microsoft.com/download/5/F/2/5F27DDF5-5C1C-4F5F-8B11-70D12A8825E5/SQLServer2019.ADMX

Does anyone know where I can find the administrative templates for any version of SQL Server 2016 or later?

I tried searching Microsoft's download center for SQL Server Administrative Templates but could not find anything except Windows Server (which do not include SQL Server admx files.

Comment: why not disable the option   that other microsoft products should be updated also

Comment: are you talking about built-in templates? SQL Server Management Studio does have built-in templates and you can use them whenever you need them. Administrative Templates (.admx) only for Windows Server not for the SQL server. https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=51957

Comment: I had the option for other microsoft products disabled in GPO but they still were installed. 

i am referring to windows administrative templates (.admx) and not the built in SSMS templates.    I am guessing MS removed the download site for 2019 version in preparation for the 2022 version.  

i was able to figure the issue out outside of this request - on the servers, they were not respecting the disabled GPO setting for other windows products.  i had to delete the registry.pol file on each server and then run a gpupdate /force to resync group policy, then the setting was turned off.